# How to back-port SQL that uses window functions to a server without them?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have to back port a MySQL 8 query to MySQL 5.7. One of the subqueries uses window functions which are not supported in the previous version. The subquery looks like this (simplified):

```
SELECT
    ROW_NUMBER()  OVER w AS `row_num`,
    MIN(`date`) OVER w AS `min_date`,
    MAX(`date`) OVER w AS `max_date`,
    `supplier_id`,
    `customer_id`
FROM `bookings`
WINDOW w AS (PARTITION BY `supplier_id`, `customer_id`)
```

How would one go about mimicking this code without using "window" functionality?

Answer (score 1):

You can write this as:

```
SELECT (@rn := @rn + 1) as row_num, bb.min_date, bb.max_date,
       b.supplier_id,
       b.customer_id
FROM bookings b CROSS JOIN
     (SELECT @rn := 0) params LEFT JOIN
     (SELECT supplier_id, customer_id, MIN(date) as min_date, MAX(date) as max_date
      FROM bookings b
      GROUP BY supplier_id, customer_id
     ) bb
     USING (supplier_id, customer_id);
```

EDIT:

Oops, the row number is using the windowing too.  So:

```
SELECT (@rn := if(sc = concat_os(':', supplier_id, customer_id), @rn + 1
                  if(@sc := concat_os(':', supplier_id, customer_id), 1, 1)
                 )
       ) as row_num,
       b.*
FROM (SELECT bb.min_date, bb.max_date,
             b.supplier_id,
             b.customer_id
      FROM bookings b CROSS JOIN
           (SELECT supplier_id, customer_id, MIN(date) as min_date, MAX(date) as max_date
            FROM bookings b
            GROUP BY supplier_id, customer_id
           ) bb
           USING (supplier_id, customer_id)
      ORDER BY supplier_id, customer_id
     ) b CROSS JOIN
     (SELECT @rn := 0, @sc := '') params
```

Comment: This gives row_num as an incrementing row number in the final result not "over window" row number, though.

Comment: @ed22 . . . Duh!  Thank you.  I amended the answer.